# Corda: Trying to put the RPC Permissions on an external database

Tags: corda

I'm trying to put the RPC Permissions, along with the users and their password on an external database. I've followed the documentation for Corda v. 3.3 (https://docs.corda.net/clientrpc.html#rpc-security-management).

It says that I need to create a "security" field for the node in question and fill out all the necessary information. I've done it, but as soon as I try to deploy the Node, it gives me this error:

*"Could not set unknown property 'security' for object of type net.corda.plugins.Node."*

The node's information looks like this in the build.gradle document:

```
node {
    name "O=myOrganisation,L=Lisbon,C=PT"
    p2pPort 10024
    rpcSettings {
        address("localhost:10025")
        adminAddress("localhost:10026")
    }
    security = {
        authService = {
            dataSource = {
                type = "DB"
                passwordEncryption = "SHIRO_1_CRYPT"
                connection = {
                    jdbcUrl = "localhost:3306"
                    username = "*******"
                    password = "*******"
                    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cordapps = [
            "$project.group:cordapp:$project.version"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing two syntaxes:

- The syntax for configuring a `node` block inside a `Cordform` task such as `deployNodes`
- The syntax for configuring a node directly via `node.conf`

The security settings are for inside `node.conf`. You have to create the node first, then modify the node's `node.conf` with these settings once it has been created.

Corda 4 will introduce an `extraConfig` option for use inside `Cordfrom` `node` blocks, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51636785/how-can-i-configure-security-per-node-in-corda-using-gradle).